# how to show the <title> in an Objective-C app

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad

I'm making an app where a label shows the title of the webpage.
I don't know where I have to start, I just know that I have to use the text inside `<head><title>*Text*</title></head>` of an HTML document.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll use a UIWebView to load the webpage. In UIWebViewDelegate, there's a method: – webViewDidFinishLoad:. This method will be called when finished loading the webpage. You can write something like below in the delegate method to get the webpage's title:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    NSString *title = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.title;"];
    //do something with title.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you will not display the Web Page, I suggest to don't use the UIWebView..

You can use ASIHTTPRequest to get the page content and parse it to get the title tag content. You will save some time, memory and CPU usage.  However, YuAo solution is really easy to implement.